# How to reformat for loop and if statements into java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I have code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (validatorClass.firstCondition(predicates, list, i)) {
        if (!validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)) {
            properData.add(list.get(i));
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how can I transfer it into java 8 code (streams). I thought about using

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(iteratedElement -> ...)
```

but I dont know how to deal with if statements as I'm struggling with `break` statement from first `if`

Answer (score 2):

If you have Java 9, that `break` behavior can be obtained by [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
var properData = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .takeWhile(i -> validatorClass.firstCondition(predicates, list, i))
    .filter(i -> !validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i))
    .mapToObj(i ->list.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if your predicate don't depend on the whole list

```
var properData = list.stream
    .takeWhile(e -> validatorClass.firstCondition(predicates, e))
    .filter(e -> !validatorClass.secondCondition(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you only use Java 8, I'm afraid you have to use a **good ol' for loop** or replace it by a while loop :

```
int i = 0;
while(i < list.size() && validatorClass.firstCondition(predicates, list, i)) {
    if (!validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)) {
        properData.add(list.get(i));
    }
    i++;
}
```

If you **really** want to use streams, what you could do is create a flag that you would modify in your filter, but it's just overcomplicating things and it's creating side effects in you filter method, which is clearly a bad idea. Here is an example for the sake of the answer but **I would strongly advice not to do that**:

```
boolean[] stop = {false};
var properData = list.stream
        .filter(e -> {
            boolean result = !stop[0] && validatorClass.firstCondition(predicates, e);
            if(!result) stop[0] = true;
            return result;
        }).filter(e -> !validatorClass.secondCondition(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you wonder why I used `boolean[]` and not `boolean`, it's because in lambdas you can only use final or effectively final variables. The array is a way to bypass that rule. 
Anyway, don't do that.

Comment: it needs to be java 8

Comment: @mara122 : I edited my answer for java 8 but long story short : keep your loop.

Comment: Okay, but so I should not introduce any modification to this? I mean change if statements somehow etc.

Comment: Yes, it's good like this. Again, if the conditions don't depend on your whole list, just use a enhanced for loop. (`for(Element element : list){}`)

Comment: Yes, I've seen, but I still think that it is overcomplicating things and furthermore it iterates twice. A for loop is way simpler.

Comment: @mara122 : by the way it might be more interesting to use a while loop, I edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your nested for loop can convert to 2 separated for loops like this:

```
int breakIndex = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (!validatorClass.firstCondition(list, i)) {
    breakIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < breakIndex; i++) {
  if (!validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)) {
    properData.add(list.get(i));
  }
}
```

Then you can convert to 2 separated IntStream.range() statements like this:

```
int breakIndex = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(i -> !validatorClass.firstCondition(list, i)).findFirst().orElse(list.size());
List<Integer> properData = IntStream.range(0, firstIndex).filter(i -> !validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)).mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have edited your code a little bit to test the result:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ValidatorClass validatorClass = new ValidatorClass();
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    List<Integer> properData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (validatorClass.firstCondition(list, i)) {
        if (!validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)) {
          properData.add(list.get(i));
        }
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Your result: " + properData);

    int breakIndex = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(i -> !validatorClass.firstCondition(list, i)).findFirst().orElse(0);
    List<Integer> properData2 = IntStream.range(0, breakIndex).filter(i -> !validatorClass.secondCondition(list, i)).mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("My result: " + properData2);
  }

  public static class ValidatorClass {
    public boolean firstCondition(List<Integer> list, int i) {
      return i < 8;
    }

    public boolean secondCondition(List<Integer> list, int i) {
      return i % 2 == 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Your result: [1, 3, 5, 7]
My result: [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Could you explain `firstIndex` variable?

Comment: @mara122 I explained more, pls check

Comment: Ye, but what about situation when it does not find breakIndex, so breakindex is gonna be 0. `Instream.range(0,0)` gonna iterate through all list?

Comment: @mara122: range(0, 0) does not iterate the list, it equals to for(int i=0; i< 0; i++)

Comment: @yelliver : then it doesn't have the same behavior as if there is not breakIndex, it should iterate through all the list.

Comment: Then I do not understand it. If it didnt find any break index., so all firstCondition calls return true, then our break index is equal to 0. So how we can iterate and collect data within secondCondition?

Comment: Maybe refactoring it into `orElse(list.size)` could resolve it?

Comment: I am checking again :D

Comment: Ye, I see that, but think about situation which I provided. I read it like this: iterate through the list, find first element which returns false, if you don't find, then return 0. Which is wrong as I need to iterate through all list if all were `true`